# Threading - Main thread running permanently and other threads are dependent on another

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

Im pretty new to python and threading. My goal was it to have one main thread that is running permanently and other threads that are dependent on another. I tried different things with `.join()` but i couldnt get an answer.

Here is a picture what ive come up with in my mind:
[Thread Imagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gpwR.png)

Do i need something like a daemon or can i solve this with just simple `.join()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that structure:

```py
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def do_work_1():
    print("Thread 1 starting")
    sleep(1)
    print("Thread 1 done")

def do_work_2(parent_thread):
    print("Thread 2 wait thread 1 to finish")
    parent_thread.join()
    print("Thread 2 starting")
    sleep(1)
    print("Thread 2 done")

def do_work_3(parent_thread):
    print("Thread 3 wait thread 2 to finish")
    parent_thread.join()
    print("Thread 3 starting")
    sleep(1)
    print("Thread 3 done")

thread1 = Thread(target=do_work_1)
thread2 = Thread(target=do_work_2, args=(thread1,)) # Do not miss the comma!
thread3 = Thread(target=do_work_3, args=(thread2,))

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()

for num in range(6):
    print("Main thread still do job", num)
    sleep(0.60)

thread3.join()
print("Job done")
```

Comment: Thank you! I kinda got a missunderstanding of the `.join()` concept. :)